# what is the way of updating array embedded document's array embedded document in mongodb [ Nested Arrays]?

Tags: mongodb

Think that I have a document like this-

```
{
_id:1,
xArray:[
  {name: "Jack", children:[{name:"J", age:10},{name:"M", age:11}]},
  {name: "Ma", children:[{name:"M", age:10},{name:"K", age:11}]}
]
}
```

Now I want to update the age of **Jack**'s child **J**'s `age`, How can I do this?
The expected result will be-

```
{
_id:1,
xArray:[
  {name: "Jack", children:[{name:"J", age:30},{name:"M", age:11}]},
  {name: "Ma", children:[{name:"M", age:10},{name:"K", age:11}]}
]
}
```

Comment: You can use arrayFitlres like this [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Jmd5Q2GgbfR)

Answer (score 0):

Answered by @turivishal

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  $set: {
    "xArray.$[xArray].children.$[children].age": 30
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "xArray.name": "Jack"
    },
    {
      "children.name": "J"
    }
  ]
})
```